# How can I use a boolean expression to match if substrings are contained in reference string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to apply boolean operators to string in order to return a true/false result from the search of some substring inside a reference string. If the reference string contains the substring boolean expression, then I want a true result.

Imagine I have a reference string like the following:

`string refString = "This is a long text made by some different words."`

And I have the following boolean expression composed by substrings:

`string expression = "This is&words"`

What I want to achieve is to return a true/false result based on the application of the boolean expression to the reference string. In this example, I want a *true* result if the reference string contains the substring *"This is"* AND the substring *"words"*.

I'm starting with something like that:

```
private const string And = @"&";
private const string Or = @"|";
private const string Xor = @"^";

private bool FindSubstring(string _refString, string _expression)
{
    string[] andExpression = _expression.Split(new string[] { And }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] orExpression = _expression.Split(new string[] { Or }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string[] xorExpression = _expression.Split(new string[] { Xor }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    if (andExpression.Length > 1)
        return andExpression.All(_refString.Contains);
    if (orExpression.Length > 1)
        return orExpression.Any(_refString.Contains);
    if (xorExpression.Length == 2)
        return _refString.Contains(xorExpression[0]) ^ _refString.Contains(xorExpression[1]);
}
```

It will work fine for simple operation with one boolean operator only, but what if I need to check for more complex expressions?

Overall it seems quite *"ugly"* and limited to me: I will add a check for escape characters in expression, I need a lot of code to deal with multiple boolean operators, I think I will go crazy to deal with complex expressions with nested parenthesis, ecc.

Does something exist like Regex, where I can just write a complex boolean pattern and match with an input string?

Comment: I could think of a recursive function that breaks down your orignial (complex) expression in small bites depending on your rules.

Answer (score 2):

> Does something exist like Regex, where I can just write a complex boolean pattern and match with an input string?

No, the expression you're trying to parse isn't a regex, it's a left-recursive context-free grammar. There's plenty of grammar parsers and lexers out there (I personally used Irony.Net and Antlr), but for this small grammar of yours you could just write a recursive descent parser of your own, you just need to translate your left-recursive grammar to a right-recursive one.

Also depending on what exactly you're doing, Lucene.Net might help. It checks boolean expressions like yours against a data store and returns the results with their "score". It's not clear from your code if it's an XY problem, or if you're really just testing against one single string.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I will check the parsers you mentioned to see if they can fit my scenario. To give more context to what I'm doing: I'm receiving SNMP trap containing long string, and I need to parse those strings and check if they contain substring specified in boolean expression.